# PHP heroku timer doesn't work due to 30seconds timeout

Tags: php, heroku, timer, timeout

Currently, I have a timer for a telegram bot that works on my own terminal, but when deployed to heroku, it causes a timeout due to it exceeding 30seconds. Hoping to find someone able to solve this issue.

I have tried setting the timer to run below 30 seconds each time, but it seems to be the sum of the time taken for the entire code, meaning I can't just set the timer to a while loop and run every 29 seconds to prevent a timeout. Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

```
public function timer($time) {
echo "$time minutes countdown starts." . PHP_EOL;

// Save the date in future when the timer should stop
$endTime = time() + $time*60;
while(true) {
    sleep($time*20);
    $secondsRemaining = $endTime - time();
    // echo 'Minutes: '.ceil($secondsRemaining/60).PHP_EOL;

    if ($secondsRemaining <= 0) {
        echo 'Finished'.PHP_EOL;
        return true;
        }
    }
}

private function timedMessages($time, $msg) {
    if($this->timer($time)) {
        $this->sendMessage($msg);
                    // method to send telegram messages
    }
}

$msg = "Start";
$this->sendMessage($msg);

$msg = "1st message";
$this->timedMessages(20, $msg);

$msg = "2nd message";               
$this->timedMessages(20, $msg);

$msg = "3rd message";
$this->timedMessages(20, $msg);
```

Expected: Run through the 60minutes, and every 20minutes send a message

Results: 'Start' message is sent every 30 seconds as heroku timeouts and rerun the code. '1st message' is still sent after 20minutes tho

If possible, I'm hoping I can find a way to run a timer with heroku, if anyone knows (I don't think cronjobs is a proper solution either...)

Comment: Sounds like php might be the wrong tool for the job. But you are restating multiple instances of this script, each time it times out, a new script is stated. It's not really something I would recommend, but you can set the timeout to infinite.

Comment: Why not using a cronjob to start the script every minute?

Comment: yea but the cronjob will run the script even when I don't need it